# Get the output device name in vlc

Tags: python, vlc

I want to get the names of the output devices in vlc. I use the audio_output_device_enum function but it does not give me the name of the main output device
My code:

```
import vlc
p=vlc.MediaPlayer("music.mp3")
mods = p.audio_output_device_enum()
if mods:
    devices=[]
    mod = mods
    while mod:
        mod = mod.contents
        devices.append(mod.device)
        mod = mod.next
print(devices[1])
```

`b'{0.0.0.00000000}.{152df11f-ed40-403e-8bf6-7916e2b74849}'`

While I want to show me the original name, Speakers (High Definition Audio).
How do I find the original output device name?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`audio_output_device_enum` contains `description` in addition to `device`
There are caveats to `audio_output_device_enum`:

> ```
>    @note: Not all audio outputs support enumerating devices.
>    The audio output may be functional even if the list is empty (None).
>    @note: The list may not be exhaustive.
>    @warning: Some audio output devices in the list might not actually work in
>    some circumstances.
> ```

```
import vlc
import time

p=vlc.MediaPlayer("vp.mp3")
mods = p.audio_output_device_enum()
if mods:
    devices=[]
    mod = mods
    while mod:
        mod = mod.contents
        devices.append([mod.device,mod.description])
        mod = mod.next
for d in devices:
    print(d)
p.play()
time.sleep(1)
while p.is_playing():
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

> [b'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo', b'Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo']